# android content provider SQLITE - how can I link between two tables that are updated in 2 different fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider

I have 2 tables:
1. Cities
2. Forecasts
the tables are currently linked by 2 fields: city and country. 
and in relation of one to many (many forecasts per one city)
each table is updated in a deferent fragmentActivity and both are displayed in the main activity.
both get data from parsing JSONs
I have another activity of the cities list.
if a city is deleted from the cities list, it is deleted from CITIES table by id (by onLongClick event in the recyclerView) 
the problem is that -  the relevant forecasts in Forecasts Table should be deleted as well.
what is the current solution? THANKS!
BTW - if it wasn't clear by now - I'm new to android. ;)

Comment: How about running **2** `DELETE` commands, one on each table? Possibly, encapsulated in a transacion.

Comment: @Rotwang  I have only the id for the entry in Cities table

Comment: How do you link the tables? There must be a field (possibly, an `id`) on which you make the JOIN. Use that field to delete both tables.